# Boost.Log: Why it is showing duplicate the message?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-log

I'm learning the Boost.Log library. I want to send messages to a file and `std::clog`. I have the following class:

```
class logger
{
    public:
        explicit logger(
            const std::string& tag,
            const std::string& file,
            bool console
        )
        {
            boost::log::register_simple_formatter_factory< boost::log::trivial::severity_level, char >("Severity");

            std::string the_format = "[%TimeStamp%] (%LineID%) [%Severity%]";
            if(!tag.empty()) {
                m_log_.add_attribute(
                    "Tag",
                    boost::log::attributes::constant< std::string >( tag )
                );
                the_format += " [%Tag%]";
            }

            the_format += ": %Message%";

            if(console) {
                boost::log::add_console_log(
                    std::clog,
                    boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true,
                    boost::log::keywords::format = the_format
                );
            }

            if(!file.empty()) {
                boost::log::add_file_log(
                    boost::log::keywords::file_name = file,
                    boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true,
                    boost::log::keywords::open_mode = (std::ios::out | std::ios::app),
                    boost::log::keywords::format = the_format
                );
            }

        }

        ~logger(void)
        { }

        void log(
            const std::string& msg
        )
        {
            BOOST_LOG_SEV ( m_log_, boost::log::trivial::info ) << msg;
        }

    private:
        boost::log::sources::severity_logger< boost::log::trivial::severity_level > m_log_;

}; // logger
```

I have the following `main()` function:

```
void x()
{
    logger lg("omega", "", true);
    lg.log( "Goodbye" );
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    logger lg( "alfa", "", true );
    lg.log( "Hello world!!!");
    x();
    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand why the duplicate message is displayed: "Hello world!!!":

```
[2016-Aug-23 17:51:36.852912] (1) [info] [alfa]: Hello world!!!
[2016-Aug-23 17:51:36.853359] (2) [info] [omega]: Goodbye
[2016-Aug-23 17:51:36.853359] (2) [info] [omega]: Goodbye
```

**UPDATE**: Sorry, the example was incomplete.

Comment: Which version of boost are you using? I cannot reproduce this with 1.58. Which platform?

Comment: @isanae, I'm sorry, the example was incomplete. I'm using the version 1.60 and the os is GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logger`'s constructor is calling `add_console_log()` and `add_file_log()`. If you construct `logger` twice, these functions will also be called twice. Since they add global sinks, every log entry will be duplicated twice on the console and in your file.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    logger lg1("1", "", true);
    logger lg2("2", "", true);
    logger lg3("3", "", true);
    logger lg4("4", "", true);

    lg1.log("test");
}
```

This will output:

```
[2016-Aug-23 13:25:56.468382] (1) [info] [1]: test
[2016-Aug-23 13:25:56.468382] (1) [info] [1]: test
[2016-Aug-23 13:25:56.468382] (1) [info] [1]: test
[2016-Aug-23 13:25:56.468382] (1) [info] [1]: test
```

You probably want some sort of reference count or flag to only call these functions once.

Comment: @isanea: Thanks, the problem was fixed. One more thing, if I use streams in the example, How do to prevent that output will be duplicated in every streams?

Comment: @JuanSolo (Make sure you type usernames correctly, or select them from the list that pops up. I didn't get a notification about your message.) What do you mean? The problem is with `add_console_log()` being called multiple times, not streams.

Comment: Now, I use files in the example. In this case, `Goodbye` appears at the output of the first logger. The documentation says that this behavior is correct. Can I change this behavior?

Comment: @JuanSolo I don't understand what behaviour you want to change. If you only call `add_console_log()` once, the output will only appear once.

Comment: :  I configure the logger to use files (I don't use the `add_console_log()` function, I use only the `add_file_log()` function). [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d7de5f63e654493), you can see an example (It is not executable because I do not know how to write files in coliru  but you can understand what I ask).

Comment: @JuanSolo I don't understand your question. Since it seems unrelated to your original one, I suggest you ask a new one with more details. You can add a comment linking to the new question here, I'll try to help more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247778/boost-log-how-to-prevent-the-output-will-be-duplicated-to-all-added-streams-whe